# How to get the type of bar code from zbar?

Tags: iphone, ios, qr-code, zbar

In my application, Zbar is decoding perfectly. But the problem is Zbar can decode both QR code and bar code. So after decoding, how do I get the type of Encoding Style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are return codes for type in ZBarSymbol. You will be looking for ZBAR_QRCODE for QR codes

[ZBarSymbol documentation](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/ZBarSymbol.html)

Something like this should help you to get the symbol out:

```
- (void) readerView: (ZBarReaderView*) view didReadSymbols: (ZBarSymbolSet*) syms  fromImage: (UIImage*) img 
{
    //do something useful with results and display resultText in resultViewController
    for(ZBarSymbol *sym in syms) 
    {
        imageResult3.image = img; 
        resultText.text = sym.typeName;
        resultText.text =  [ resultText.text stringByAppendingString:@" - " ];
        resultText.text =  [ resultText.text stringByAppendingString:sym.data ]; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man.. :-) Now could you tell me how do I get last modification date of that image .. ??? All code tried but no luck ..

Answer (score 0):

What i did was,

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ZBarImage *zImage = [[ZBarImage alloc] initWithCGImage:image.CGImage];
    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = [[ZBarImageScanner alloc] init];
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                        config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                        to: 0];
    [scanner scanImage:zImage];
    ZBarSymbolSet *set = [scanner results];

    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;
    for (symbol in set)
        break;
    codeType.text = symbol.typeName
}
```