# How to get type of Encoding Style of QR/bar-code with python-qrtools/ZBar?

Tags: python, objective-c, qr-code, zbar

On my Ubuntu server I've installed the [python-qrtools package](https://launchpad.net/qr-tools) (which makes use of [zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/)) using `sudo apt-get install python-qrtools` to decode images of QR-codes and bar-codes in Python like this:

```
>>> qr = qrtools.QR()
>>> qr.decode('the_qrcode_or_barcode_image.jpg')
True
>>> print qr.data
Hello! :)
```

This works perfectly fine.

I now want to store this data and regenerate the image at a later point in time. But the problem is that I don't know whether the original image was a QR-code or some type of bar-code. I checked all properties of the `qr` object, but none of them seems to give me the type of Encoding Style (QR/bar/other).

In [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587917/how-to-get-the-type-of-code-from-zbar) it is described that ZBar does give back the type of Encoding Style, but it only gives an example in Objective-C, plus I'm not sure if this is actually an answer to what I am looking for.

Does anybody know how I can find out the type of Encoding Style (so QR-code/BAR-code/other) in Python (preferably using the python-qrtools package)? And if not in Python, are there any Linux command line tools which can find this out? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source of  qrtools, I cannot see any way to get the type but there is a [zbar](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbar) python lib, based on the `scan_image` [example](https://github.com/ZBar/ZBar/blob/master/python/examples/scan_image.py), the code below seems to do what you want:

```
import zbar
import Image

scanner = zbar.ImageScanner()

scanner.parse_config('enable')

img = Image.open("br.png").convert('L')
width, height = img.size
stream = zbar.Image(width, height, 'Y800', img.tostring())

scanner.scan(stream)

for symbol in stream:
    print 'decoded', symbol.type, 'symbol', '"%s"' % symbol.data
```

Using a random barcode I grabbed from the [net](https://www.google.ie/search?q=barcode&sa=X&espv=2&biw=1041&bih=489&site=webhp&tbm=isch&imgil=M5V7J_u2RcL3xM%253A%253BZ_cQMxfTqODJ9M%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.elpnow.org%25252F2013%25252F08%25252F08%25252Fyou-might-need-a-barcode%25252F&source=iu&pf=m&fir=M5V7J_u2RcL3xM%253A%252CZ_cQMxfTqODJ9M%252C_&usg=__b-nLxM3tk_2cyAbY4DIBN38KpFo%3D&ved=0CCkQyjdqFQoTCK7AhuS3sMcCFa0H2wodGOALdQ&ei=Kv7RVa6DFa2P7AaYwK-oBw#imgrc=M5V7J_u2RcL3xM%3A&usg=__b-nLxM3tk_2cyAbY4DIBN38KpFo%3D):

```
decoded UPCA symbol "123456789012"
```

Using this [qr code](https://www.google.ie/search?q=qr%20code&espv=2&biw=1041&bih=489&tbm=isch&imgil=-ayNRtSP2mF7BM%253A%253BRay_E7IhfbU0KM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.reichmann-racing.de%25252F%25253Fpage_id%2525253D638&source=iu&pf=m&fir=-ayNRtSP2mF7BM%253A%252CRay_E7IhfbU0KM%252C_&usg=__vp9rtqyApB4uo0HAmxHWJ3vvlnM%3D&ved=0CD4QyjdqFQoTCOew4IG4sMcCFW1H2wodanMAnw&ei=aP7RVefcJu2O7Qbq5oH4CQ#imgrc=-ayNRtSP2mF7BM%3A&usg=__vp9rtqyApB4uo0HAmxHWJ3vvlnM%3D) outputs:

```
 decoded QRCODE symbol "http://www.reichmann-racing.de"
```

Comment: Hi Padraic. Thanks a million for that code! Works like a charm. Just a last question; do you know what the `'Y800'` refers to?

Comment: @Kramer,you're welcome.The third argument is the  image format four-character code, the images must be either  `"Y800"(greyscale)` or `"GRAY"` for zbar.